# ImportError: No module named App1.views (django 1.5). Any idea?

Tags: django

I have 2 Apps in myproject. When I try to import App1 views from App2 views, I get **ImportError: No module named App1.views**. for e.g (from myproject.App1.views import *). And I added both apps under INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django 1.5, you need to omit the project name from the imports. The [release notes of Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py) explains this change in the applicatiion structure and import paths. So the correct import statement is:

```
from App1.views import *
```